# how to wait for api response for rendering for page source

Tags: angular, async-await, metadata, angular-universal

I'm working on page source and meta tags, meta tags are dependent on reset api call

```
 getMetaData(type): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL_API}/seo/get_seo_meta_data?slug=${type}`).subscribe(rs => {
      const seoData = rs['data'];
      this.settingSEoData({
        title: seoData['title'],
        description: seoData['description'],
        keywords: seoData['keywords'],
        author: seoData['author'],
        robots: seoData['robots'],
        og: {
          title: seoData['ogTitle'],
          description: seoData['ogDescription'],
          type: seoData['ogType'],
          url: seoData['ogUrl'],
          image: seoData['ogImage'],
        }
      })
    });
}
```

I tried the code below at component level

```
this.helperSRV.waitForOneSecond(500).then(r => getMetaData('abc'));
```

Output:

```
{"data":{"id":0,"seoPageId":30764,"slug":"cat-65","title":"Rentage - Power Air and Light","description":"This is a Test Machine to check the load capability of the site","keywords":"Propulsion Diesel Working Height Width Weight Power ","author":"Manufacturer Atlas Copco JLG Manitou","ogType":"Category","ogTitle":"Rentage - Power Air and Light","ogUrl":"https://machinesrentals.com/search-result/power-air-and-light?categories=65&subcategories=0","ogImage":"https://machinesrentals.com/mr_users_media/1325/thumbnail_NnUszt075Xntmm807XHZKqLB8yRajkR21Mbl1qqU.jpeg","ogDescription":"This is a Test Machine to check the load capability of the site","robots":"noindex"},"resultsCount":0,"error":[]}
```

Method's body

```
  settingSEOo(seoData) {
    if (seoData) {
      console.log(seoData)

      if (seoData.title !== '') {
        this.titleService.setTitle(seoData.title);
        this.metaService.addTag({ name: 'title', content: seoData.title }, true);
      }
      if (seoData.keywords !== '')
        this.metaService.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: seoData.keywords });

  }
```

It's working fine in local but not in dev and prod, not generating meta tags. Can you help?

Comment: Can you show the code for `this.settingSEoData`? And your `index.html` page

Comment: description is updated

Comment: Do you already have the tags in `index.html`? Do you have any error server side? Is the Output above from your console.log? Then you need to reference `seoData.data.title`

Comment: onlu these in index
  `<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">` no any error in serverside im getting response
Output: `{"data":{"id":0,"seoPageId":30764,"slug":"cat-65","title":"Rentage ...."} }` as mentioned in question

Comment: Then you need to use `seoData.data.title` and not `seoData.title`

Comment: `const seoData = rs['data'];
      this.settingSEoData({
        title: seoData['title'],
        description: seoData['description'],
        keywords: seoData['keywords'],
        author: seoData['author'],
        robots: seoData['robots'],
        og: {
          title: seoData['ogTitle'],
          description: seoData['ogDescription'],
          type: seoData['ogType'],
          url: seoData['ogUrl'],
          image: seoData['ogImage'],
        }
      })`
im sending rs['data'] to that function

Comment: You said the output was from your console log above, which is in your method right before accessing the `title` and `keywords` properties. That output shows a `data` key in your object, hence my suggestion. If not, please post the correct code and output.

Comment: im doing copy of data into seoData and sending object to methed for meta tags